# Convenient way to create a wrapper

Tags: java

**Problem**

I need to perform logic over and over on the results of several methods. The methods can have arbitrary result types. The simple use case looks like this:

A wrapper class with an execute method:

```
/**
 * Wrapper class which executes inner logic, processes the result of that logic and returns the processed result.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public abstract class Wrapper<T> {    
    /**
     * Perform inner logic
     */
    public abstract T run();

    /**
     * Invoke inner logic and process it.
     */
    public T execute() {            
        T result = run();           
        // TODO: process result         
        return result;
    }       
}
```

And the logic in an inner class, example usage of the Wrapper:

```
public class WrapperDemo {      
    /**
     * Simple invocation of the inner logic and then the outer logic
     */
    public static Boolean testMethod() {        
        // wrap around logic and execute
        return new Wrapper<Boolean>() {    
            @Override
            public Boolean run() {                  
                // TODO: perform logic, simply returning true for now 
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }               
        }.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        // demo method invocation
        Boolean result = WrapperDemo.testMethod();          
        // process result
        System.out.println(result);         
        System.exit(0);         
    }       
}
```

I'll have to apply this to several 100s of methods.

**Question**

Does anyone know a more convenient way to code this with less code for `testMethod` (e. g. maybe annotation)?

Comment: Are you using Java 8? You could use lambda expressions.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit about what kind of the "real" content that your run() methods will have? In other words: what are the "common" factories in your context?

Comment: And an unrelated code-quality side node: consider **not** having useless javadoc such as `@return with no content!` around. Either you write up real javadoc, then put in content; or leave out the javadoc. But empty javadoc serves only **one** purpose: wasting brain CPU cycles in order to **ignore** that empty, useless comment. (I went forward and removed them from your question so other readers can focus on the real question ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat The run method e. g. retrieves data from a data source. In the wrapper the data are post-processed and then returned to the caller. I stripped down the example code to a minimum. Ok on the javadoc, thanks for removing it :-)

Comment: If you want to do this using annotations and without any framework, you'll have to use a proxy-based framework, like Java's own [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) (which only supports interface), [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib), [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) or [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/). I don't know how those will be compatible with Java 9 (which comes out soonish). I discourage using them directly unless needed, but use an intermediate DI framework which helps you getting there (Guice comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 8, you could write the following:

```
public static <T> T execute(Wrapper<T> wrapper) {
  return wrapper.execute();
}
```

And then use it as following:

```
public static Boolean testMethod() {
  return execute(()-> {
    return Boolean.TRUE;
  });
}
```

---

Though I fail to see how this is better than the following:

```
public static <T> T wrap(T result) {
  // Process result
  return result
}
```

And using it like this:

```
public static Boolean testMethod() {
  return wrap(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: My situation seems to be identical to using the [callable mechanism in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-types-and-method-arguments). I keep the question open for a few days, maybe someone knows a more convenient soltuion via annotations. Otherwise yours is just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, by combination of lambda and default method, you can achieve similar thing without much change in your API (except you need to make `Wrapper` an interface instead of abstract class)

```
public interface Wrapper<T> {    
    public T run();

    default public T execute() {            
        T result = run();
        // TODO: process result
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it by

```
public static Boolean testMethod() {
    Wrapper<Boolean> w = ()-> {return Boolean.TRUE;};
    return w.execute();
}
```

---

But personally I don't think it make much sense.

If you want to add extra logic around a logic, probably what you need is a little twist:

```
public class ExtraAction<T> {
    Supplier<T> supplier;
    public ExtraAction(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }
    public T execute() {
        T result = this.supplier.get();
        // some extra processsing
        return result;
    }
}
```

so it will be called like

```
Boolean result = new ExtraAction<>(()->{return Boolean.TRUE}).execute();
```

---

Even better, make your logic in `Wrapper` a `Function<X,Y>`, and make up something to chain your `Supplier` and `Function` together, so it will look like

```
result = Foo.forInput( ()-> { return logicToGetResult(); })
            .doExtra(ExtraAction::whateverAction).result();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use annotations, you should use a tool that allows such reflection to be used. Basic reflection can't be used because then you can't "intercept" the call. Java's Proxy might help, but you're constrained to use interfaces, which is not always what people want.

[cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/) is a library that removes all that hassle. With that, you can try the following:

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Wrap {
}

class Demo {
  @Wrap
  public Boolean testMethod() {
    return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
}

class Wrapper {
  public <T> T newInstance(Class<T> type) {
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(type);
    enhancer.setCallback(new InvocationHandler(){
      @Override public Object invoke(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        Object result = proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Wrap.class)) {
          execute(result);
        }
        return result;
      }
    });
    return enhancer.create();
  }

  public void execute(Object result) {
    // Add custom behavior to @Wrap-ped methods.
  }
}
```

Then you have to call the wrapper like this:

```
Demo demo = new Wrapper().newInstance(Demo.class);
demo.testMethod();
```

Other libraries exist too, like Byte Buddy or Javassist. But be careful because Java 9 is very close and forced those libraries into changing their core business very, very quick, possibly making them unstable.

Comment: Note: this is a separate answer because it's an entirely different approach than my previous answer.

Comment: but it does not simplify the `testMethod` as OP asked for

Comment: Yes it does: just `return Boolean.TRUE;` and `@Wrap` instead of `return new Wrapper<Boolean>(){public Boolean run(){return Boolean.TRUE;}}.execute();`. How is that not more simple?

Comment: I guess we are having different understanding for OP's question.  My understanding is, he need to write arbitrary piece of code (which he is doing by the anonymous inner class now) and decorate it with extra logic (`execute()` in his `Wrapper`).  By using your way, he still need to create a concrete class, constructing the wrapper manually etc, which does not result in shorter code.  Anyway, I guess it is actually an X-Y question, for which OP may better provide more information on he is trying to do.

Comment: For 1method, I agree. For 100? I think it does.

Comment: unless he is putting all that 100 methods in just a few classes, then what saved is 1-2 lines for class declaration for each method.

Comment: But indeed, the question is at best X-Y, at worst unclear.

Comment: Regarding the problem of several methods, one can think of several annotations and to each a specific `Function` is matched. The solution I wrote is only there to show the possibility, it's only an example, just like the question is only an example. There are entire frameworks based on this type of behavior.